# Find real date based on "DayOfWeek, Day/Month"

Tags: c#, datetime

#### Context:

In a weird Csv import we have some  miss formated Date that needs to some search. The Csv can't be fix, no control on it, we have to import it.

In Csv line :

> "FooBarName ;;Mer 30/05 ;Kbr5 08h00-13h00 (-00h10)         Kbr5 13h15-16h55;e 07h59  S 13h00  e 13h12  s 16h02;08h00-13h00 13h15-16h55;6:30;6:30;;6:30;;;;"

We have a date in a weird format: It look like a handcrafed R/r Format, that get cut to 12 char like if it was a `dd/MM/yyyy`.

> "ddd dd/MM "

I know that the last date are recent . And are ordered.

Sample date:

```
new string[] {
"Mer 15/06","Jeu 16/06","Ven 17/06","Sam 18/06","Dim 19/06","Lun 20/06","Mar 21/06",
"Jeu 23/06","Ven 24/06","Sam 25/06","Dim 26/06","Lun 27/06","Mar 28/06","Mer 29/06",
"Jeu 30/06","Ven 01/07","Sam 02/07","Dim 03/07","Lun 04/07","Mar 05/07","Mer 06/07"
}
```

#### How do I convert a string like "ddd dd/MM" into a `List<DateTime>`?

For now to find the date that can give this output I compute all date on a range and compare them to the said format.

```
CultureInfo fr = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

var endDate = DateTime.Now;
var startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year-15,1,1);

var allDates = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days)
                  .Select(x => startDate.AddDays(x))
                  .Select(x => new { key = x, strDay = x.ToString("ddd"), strOther = x.ToString(" dd/MM", fr) })
                  // French format for ddd has a dot at the end. Let's remove it.               
                  .Select(x =>new { key = x.key, str = x.strDay.Remove(x.strDay.Length - 1) + x.strOther})
                  .ToArray();

foreach (var wDate in datesToFind)
{
    var results = dates.Where(x => x.str == wDate);

    // etc..
}
```

Comment: Hate to say it but `GIGO`.

Comment: @RichardSchneider, Those a real treasure you learn to cherish. As artefact from the past that will brings nostalgia. Notes that in the last hour I have check 5 date per week employee on a 120+ employee factory for the last 24 year and still no error.

Comment: It is solvable but the answer is not a datetime, it is a list of datetimes. I still haven't seen a rule for selecting one.  "for the last 24 year" is not solvable without extra information or rules.

Comment: @bommelding, From the question **"into a List<DateTime>"**. Yes exactly! The process of selecting is outside of the scope of the question but if you want more detail I can give them: Basically All those data comes from worked Shift appointment. And are send by a device on a rs232 cable sending every employee that ever use it one by one. Those information are then store in csv file. I know when an employ leaved so the last pointage he made should be clause to the leave date. Then every pointage before that must be close to the previous one if you take the appointments in reverse order.

Comment: Old badging and attendance system could be fun. Especially when you are trying to get the information out of them. I don't know who had the idea of making such an export using serial port rs232 collecting employee per employee in creation order, from each badge station, before sending them to the "Brain".

Answer (score 1):

What happens to the year in the datetime? Do you have any specific year or do you try to find for example "In which year was the 1st of July a Sunday"? If the latter is the case that's not reliable as for example the 1st of July was on Sunday in 2018, 2012 etc. Can you do something like:

```
    var dateStrings = new string[] {
    "Mer 15/06","Jeu 16/06","Ven 17/06","Sam 18/06","Dim 19/06","Lun 20/06","Mar 21/06",
    "Jeu 23/06","Ven 24/06","Sam 25/06","Dim 26/06","Lun 27/06","Mar 28/06","Mer 29/06",
    "Jeu 30/06","Ven 01/07","Sam 02/07","Dim 03/07","Lun 04/07","Mar 05/07","Mer 06/07"
    };
var year = GetYear(dateStrings[0]);
var listDates = dateStrings
    .Select(x => {
        var input = x.Split(' ')[1].Split('/');

        return new DateTime(year, Convert.ToInt32(input[1]), Convert.ToInt32(input[0])); 
    }).ToList();
```

Technically you need just one day to get the year (if you know that the list of days is from the same year):

```
private int GetYear(string dateString){
    var year = DateTime.Today.Year;
    var tempString = dateString.Split(' ');
    var weekDay = tempString[0];

    var monthDate = tempString[1].Split('/');

    var month = Convert.ToInt32(monthDate[1]);
    var date = Convert.ToInt32(monthDate[0]);

    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

    switch (weekDay) {
        case "Lun":
            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
            break;
        case "Mar":
            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
            break;
        case "Mer":
            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
            break;
        case "Jeu":
            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Thursday;
            break;
        case "Ven":
            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday;
            break;
        case "Sam":
            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
            break;
        default:
            dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
            break;

    }

    while (year > 2003) {
        var temp = new DateTime(year, month, date); 
        if (temp.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek) {
            return year;
        }

        year--;
    }
    return year;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yep it's about how to find datetime where "1st of July is  a Sunday"

Answer (score 1):

I went about this in a manner very similar to Svetoslav Petrov, but instead of assuming that all of the given dates fall within the same year, I work through the set of date strings in reverse order and in each iteration of the loop determine the most recent year (a) that is equal to or earlier than the year of the most recently converted date and (b) in which the given day of the week is valid. This approach *should* be valid as long as there isn't a many-year gap between any two consecutive dates in the series, or between the last date in the series and the current date.

```
void Test()
{
    var dateStrings = new string[] {
        "Mer 15/06","Jeu 16/06","Ven 17/06","Sam 18/06","Dim 19/06","Lun 20/06","Mar 21/06",
        "Jeu 23/06","Ven 24/06","Sam 25/06","Dim 26/06","Lun 27/06","Mar 28/06","Mer 29/06",
        "Jeu 30/06","Ven 01/07","Sam 02/07","Dim 03/07","Lun 04/07","Mar 05/07","Mer 06/07"
        };

    var parsedDates = ParseDateStrings(dateStrings);
    foreach (var date in parsedDates)
        Console.WriteLine(date);
}

// Takes a set of date strings in the format described by the question and returns
// the analogous set of DateTime objects. This method assumes that the supplied
// dates are in chronological order.
List<DateTime> ParseDateStrings(IEnumerable<string> dateStrings)
{
    var year = DateTime.Today.Year;
    var parsedDates = new List<DateTime>();

    // Since we can't know at first how many years are represented in the given
    // data set, we can't really make any assumptions about the year in which the
    // data begins. Instead we assume that the most recent date occurs in either
    // the current year or the latest previous year in which that date was valid,
    // and work through the set backwards.
    foreach (var dateString in dateStrings.Reverse())
    {
        var dayOfWeek = GetDayOfWeek(dateString.Substring(0, 3));
        var day = int.Parse(dateString.Substring(4, 2));
        var month = int.Parse(dateString.Substring(7, 2));
        year = GetMostRecentValidYear(year, month, day, dayOfWeek);
        parsedDates.Add(new DateTime(year, month, day));
    }

    // Reversing our output again at this point puts the results back into the
    // same order as the inputs.
    parsedDates.Reverse();
    return parsedDates;
}

// Gets the appropriate DayOfWeek value for the given three-character abbreviation.
DayOfWeek GetDayOfWeek(string abbreviation)
{
    switch (abbreviation.ToLower())
    {
        case "dim": return DayOfWeek.Sunday;
        case "lun": return DayOfWeek.Monday;
        case "mar": return DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
        case "mer": return DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
        case "jeu": return DayOfWeek.Thursday;
        case "ven": return DayOfWeek.Friday;
        case "sam": return DayOfWeek.Saturday;
        default: throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}

// Gets the latest year that is equal to or earlier than the given year, and in
// which the given day of the given month fell on the given day of the week.
int GetMostRecentValidYear(int year, int month, int day, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    while (!YearIsValid(year, month, day, dayOfWeek))
        --year;

    return year;
}

// Returns a flag indicating whether the given day of the given month fell on the
// given day of the week in the given year.
bool YearIsValid(int year, int month, int day, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) =>
    (month != 2 || day != 29 || IsLeapYear(year)) &&
    new DateTime(year, month, day).DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek;

// Returns a flag indicating whether the given year was a leap year.
bool IsLeapYear(int year) =>
    (year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
```

Output:

```
2016-06-15 00:00:00
2016-06-16 00:00:00
2016-06-17 00:00:00
2016-06-18 00:00:00
2016-06-19 00:00:00
2016-06-20 00:00:00
2016-06-21 00:00:00
2016-06-23 00:00:00
2016-06-24 00:00:00
2016-06-25 00:00:00
2016-06-26 00:00:00
2016-06-27 00:00:00
2016-06-28 00:00:00
2016-06-29 00:00:00
2016-06-30 00:00:00
2016-07-01 00:00:00
2016-07-02 00:00:00
2016-07-03 00:00:00
2016-07-04 00:00:00
2016-07-05 00:00:00
2016-07-06 00:00:00
```

**Edit**: I was looking at this again and spotted a bug in my original implementation of `YearIsValid`: trying to construct a `DateTime` for a February 29th in a non-leap year will cause the constructor to throw. I added a test for leap years to work around this problem. `YearIsValid` will still throw if you give it an input that is not valid in *any* year, like February 30th, but in that case an exception is the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

First, it looks like you need to handle the concept of a "day in year" (localized in the french culture). This concept of "day in year" is year independant and should have the capability to yield every possible `DateTime` which are valid (since a starting year ?).

You can come up with something like that to implement this concept:

```
sealed class FrenchDayInYear
{
    private readonly string _dayOfYear;
    private readonly DateTimeFormatInfo _fr;
    public FrenchDayInYear(string dayOfYear)
    {
        _dayOfYear = dayOfYear;
        _fr = new CultureInfo("fr-FR").DateTimeFormat;
        _fr.AbbreviatedDayNames = new[] { "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam", "Dim" };
    }
    public IReadOnlyList<DateTime> PossibleDates(int startYear)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(startYear, DateTime.Now.Year - startYear)
                         .Select(WithYear)
                         .OfType<DateTime>()
                         .ToList();
    }
    private DateTime? WithYear(int year)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(_dayOfYear + year, "ddd dd/MMyyyy", _fr, DateTimeStyles.None, out var result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes about this code:

- I had to define custom `AbbreviatedDayNames` since the standard is expecting a dot a the end and yours don't contain it
- I requested the `startYear` since you didn't explicitely stated at which year one should try to find a possible date. I also assumed that the maximal year is the current year
- The trick to be able to parse an incomplete `DateTime` without getting exceptions is to defer the parsing until you have enough information (in this case in `WithYear` the missing year information is provided)
- `OfType` filters out null values
- I returned an `IReadOnlyCollection` in `PossibleDates()` to make clear that the result set has been computed and is finished

Possible usage:

```
        var inputs = new string[]
        {
            "Mer 15/06","Jeu 16/06","Ven 17/06","Sam 18/06","Dim 19/06","Lun 20/06","Mar 21/06",
            "Jeu 23/06","Ven 24/06","Sam 25/06","Dim 26/06","Lun 27/06","Mar 28/06","Mer 29/06",
            "Jeu 30/06","Ven 01/07","Sam 02/07","Dim 03/07","Lun 04/07","Mar 05/07","Mer 06/07"
        };
        var output = inputs.ToDictionary(input => input, input => new FrenchDayInYear(input).PossibleDates(2000));
        foreach (var kv in output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}=[{1}]", kv.Key, string.Join(",", kv.Value));
        }
```

The above code will yield dates from the year 2004 and 2010, the two possible years between 2000 and now (2018) where these `DayInYear` were possible.